# Redirect all traffic to home page, except for one page

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect all traffic to the home page, except anything that has the directory of /google/. I would like to keep the default Wordpress rewrite in tact, so that index.php gets removed.

```
# Need to leave certain files alone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(gif|jpeg|png|css|js|woff|ttf|eot|svg|otf|woff2|jpg)$ 

# No redirects on home page (obviously)
http://example.com

# Everything else should redirect back to http://example.com (home)
http://example.com/*

# All variations of the following should NOT redirect
http://example.com/google/
http://example.com/google
http://example.com/google/index.php
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this rule to achieve your use case.

```
RewriteRule !^google($|/) http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What's the usage in conjunction with default WP rules? I attempted similar rules and they resulted in a redirect loop. I'll give this a shot and mark as an answer, if it works. Thanks